# MvcSiteMapProvider custom path for display templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, mvcsitemapprovider

Is it possible to place display templates in a custom folder, for example, in the **DisplayTemplates/Sitemap** ?

Answer (score 0):

Create your sub-folder and move your views and they'll still work.  No other set-up required!